# clickhouse: groupBitmap slow than uniqExact?

Tags: clickhouse

I compared the use of groupBitmap and uniqExact：uniqExact is twice as fast as groupBitmap:

```sql
ClickHouseqlwp0001.mrs-41io.com :) select groupBitmap(LO_ORDERKEY) from lineorder

SELECT groupBitmap(LO_ORDERKEY)
FROM lineorder

Query id: a48055ca-bbfa-4937-b551-07c2c321a77c

┌─groupBitmap(LO_ORDERKEY)─┐
│ 414044233 │
└──────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 49.457 sec. Processed 1.66 billion rows, 6.62 GB (33.49 million rows/s., 133.95 MB/s.)

ClickHouseqlwp0001.mrs-41io.com :) select uniqExact(LO_ORDERKEY) from lineorder

SELECT uniqExact(LO_ORDERKEY)
FROM lineorder

Query id: bef46061-59d6-4121-aba4-68a74660efac

┌─uniqExact(LO_ORDERKEY)─┐
│ 414044233 │
└────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 29.201 sec. Processed 1.66 billion rows, 6.62 GB (56.72 million rows/s., 226.87 MB/s.)
```

Comment: Clickhouse have some sort of the cache relying of OS page cache. So the first attemp my be slower because of that. Can you try to use clickhouse-benchmark? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/utilities/clickhouse-benchmark/

Comment: Both functions should be tested repeatedly based on the same environment, which appears to be the time delay of the function calculation.